# How to filter smart contracts via method signature

Tags: alchemy

is there anyone here who is an expert on dune/ethereum etl/alchemy? the question is - i'm doing research and want to find a quick way to query all smart contracts that implement/have called a certain method (all the kind of swaps methods, swapAnd, swapTo, swap(address[],uint256.. dex/related research, in general). is there any option to quickly assemble smart contracts implementing a certain method? I tried to find out through dune.com api but there is no smart contract signatures filter, only for transactions, memory-inefficient way (responces too large due all kind of swaps popularity, dune have query limits it seems). ethereum etl require download all traces, too time-inefficient.